# How to get / set Unity Editor main window title?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mono, unity-editor

I'm creating a tool that shows your current branch in Unity window title.

**But I cannot get or set the title**. So far I managed to set [`title`](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/96187e5fc1a23847206bf66b6f2d0e4a1ad43301/Editor/Mono/ContainerWindow.cs#L250) property, I used [`Internal_SetTitle`](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/96187e5fc1a23847206bf66b6f2d0e4a1ad43301/Editor/Mono/ContainerWindow.bindings.cs#L88) (using Reflection), but the values does not show up in the actual window title.

On the contrary, I can set [`position`](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/96187e5fc1a23847206bf66b6f2d0e4a1ad43301/Editor/Mono/ContainerWindow.bindings.cs#L37) property of main window just fine using the same method.

Did anybody manage to alter the title using `UnityEditor` classes?

---

(Probably I could work the issue around by creating native plugins for that, but I'd prefer a cross-platform / Mono solution if there is any)

Comment: Have you tried setting the underlying private field `m_title` directly through reflection?

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues Thanks for getting back! The weird thing: I did try. And it sets the field (I read it back). But still, the values do not show up in the actual window title.

Comment: Maybe in the code, the title bar text is set just once when the window is created, or responding to specific events, like loading a project.

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues I tried to set the property on every frame, without any result. As the title is somewhat dynamic (responds to scene / platform changes), it is probably set numerous times during Editor runtime.

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues I ended up creating a native plugin. 

Comment: Good decision, i think

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues I don't really like it, I wanted to share the plugin with Windows folks as well, now it is macOS only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this isn't quite what you're after but could complement your solution, or help others in a similar situation, here is Windows only PInvoke approach to get the window handle and title of that window, associated with your current thread.

You could add use of the `SetWindowText` WinAPI as well to set the title, although you may need to do this whenever there is a configuration change as you've mentioned.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc lpEnumFunc, IntPtr lParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetWindowText")]
private static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpWindowText, int nMaxCount);

delegate bool EnumWindowsProc(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam);

private static string GetUnityEditorWindowName()
{
    var processId = (uint)Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
    var windowHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
    string result = "";

    EnumWindows((hWnd, lParam) =>
    {
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, out var windowProcessId);

        if (windowProcessId != processId) 
            return true;
        
        var titleBuilder = new StringBuilder(256);
        GetWindowText(hWnd, titleBuilder, titleBuilder.Capacity);

        if (titleBuilder.Length <= 0) 
            return true;
        
        result = titleBuilder.ToString();
        windowHandle = hWnd;
        return false;

    }, IntPtr.Zero);

    if (windowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Failed to find Unity Editor Window");
    }

    return result;
}
```